# Re-attaching Tablet Lithium Ion Battery With DC Power Pigtails

Tags: dc, lithium-ion

Complete electrical newbie here. Please forgive my ignorance.

I have a tablet that gets "circuit locked" or something. It refuses to detect the charged battery. It seems to charge the battery, but won't turn on thinking there is no battery or the battery has no power. The battery is (was) soldered directly to the circuit board. I detached the battery and hit the power a button a few times to possibly flush out capacitors locking the circuit (if that's how that even works, again, I apologize for the ignorance). After that, and re-attaching the battery, it worked fine. I assume this will happen again, so I want to use DC power pigtails (example: http://amzn.com/B00PZVDPTM ) to attach the battery in a way that can more easily be detached and re-attached.

I'm playing with a lithium-ion battery circuit here. It seems simple, but I'm concerned that I may be overlooking something. Will this work? Does it make sense? Would the DC power pigtails provide the same back and forth charging/discharging circuit that the direct solder to circuit board connection had? Is there a greater short circuit risk using the pigtails?

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: *Complete electrical newbie here* Then maybe you shouldn't fiddle with your tablet ? Are you sure this is a hardware related issue ? Have you tried factory-resetting the tablet ? You should not use such a 2-pin connector for the battery as the battery usually has **three** connections, plus, minus and one extra for a temperature sensor. Disconnecting the battery is a soft-reset so this points to a software issue.

Comment: True, maybe I shouldn't. It just seemed simple to me, and am still curious about any feedback/answers regardless if I proceed or not. No, I didn't factory reset because there is valuable data in the device storage. There are only two wires that are connecting the battery to the board.

Comment: Also note that many lithium-ion batteries can be dangerous. Unlike other battery types which may only get warm or "vent" harmlessly if accidentally mis-wired, Li-Ion are known to catch fire or worse. So "experimenting" with this particular device may be dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to switch the power on and off (if you don't really care about the tablet and absolutely have to hack it) then use a switch. There are surface mount switch that might even be able to fit on the back of the tablet and you might be able to drill a hole in the back to switch it on and off. This is assuming you have any soldering skills at all, and if you don't I wouldn't pick this to be the first project to hone them in.

A bullet connector might work, (or any other connector) just keep in mind that it will prove difficult to fit the battery and cables back in the tablet. You also have to worry about not shorting out any connector on anything else inside the tablet if its flopping around.

My recommendation: most tablets have a sequence between the power off key or a different key that shuts the tablet down or reset it. If that doesn't work, its always easier to let the battery draw down than open it up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is, nothing I tried short of removing the battery was helping. I don't plan on using the switch or connector often, just when it gets stuck again. A switch does make a lot more sense. I'm sure I can find something small and fitting (if I proceed).